# Check if device is landscape via ADB

Tags: android

Is it possible to check a devices orientation via ADB?

Not by installing any software, calling any existing software, just through ADB. Would guess there is a status file somewhere in `/proc`, but could not find it yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done through the following command:

```
adb shell dumpsys | grep 'SurfaceOrientation' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

The output will be an integer ranging from 0 to 3 for each of the four possible orientations. 0 and 2 are landscapes while 1 and 3 are portraits. As the `dumpsys` output is very large, the command might take a few seconds to complete.

**Update:** dgmltn's modification is likely much faster:

```
adb shell dumpsys input | grep 'SurfaceOrientation' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Magic! Executing the command takes a while though. `% time adb shell` =>
`adb shell dumpsys  0.01s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 9.001 total` about 9 seconds on a Nexus 7. Good catch anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @TVK : 0 is portrait and 1 is landscape,  you mentioned it reverse. anyways thanks

Comment: Perhaps it differs per device then. I'm pretty certain that these values were correct on an early Galaxy Tab model.

Comment: It's much faster if you limit dumpsys to input:

`adb shell dumpsys input | grep 'SurfaceOrientation' |  awk '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: taking those a step further: `adb shell dumpsys input | awk '/SurfaceOrientation/ {print $2}'`

That will then only process lines in awk which match the regex specified.

Comment: @Oxi It seems to differ between device models. My current guess is that 0 = default orientation (portrait for phones, landscape for tablets),  1 = rotated by 90°

Comment: This doesn't work for android 13, `SurfaceOrientation` is absent in dumpsys' output

Answer (score 2):

Verified on both Pixel and Pixel Tablet, could use

```
adb shell dumpsys window displays | grep 'DisplayFrmaes'
```

The result is like `DisplayFrames w=1080 h=2340 r=0`

And r=0,1,2,3 is the display orientation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if something has changed since the last answers were written, or if it is because I am emulating a different device.
but neither `SurfaceOrientation` nor `mLandscapeRotation` showed up in dumpsys for me.
After diffing the outputs of `dumpsys` between rotations I found
`mPredictedRotation`

```
#Normal
$./adb shell dumpsys window displays | grep 'mPredictedRotation'
        mPredictedRotation=0

#Right
$./adb shell dumpsys window displays | grep 'mPredictedRotation'
        mPredictedRotation=3

#Inverted
$./adb shell dumpsys window displays | grep 'mPredictedRotation'
        mPredictedRotation=2
$Left
#./adb shell dumpsys window displays | grep 'mPredictedRotation'
        mPredictedRotation=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution:

```
adb shell dumpsys window | grep -i surfaceorientation | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this method `content query --uri content://settings/system --projection name:value --where "name='user_rotation'"` after opening `adb shell` . Although doesn't seem to work if entered without opening a shell first.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, I would like to point out that the return value of `adb shell dumpsys | grep 'SurfaceOrientation'` does not always follow a specific rule across devices ("0 and 2 are landscapes while 1 and 3 are portraits" is wrong).

I improved the method by an additional query, which advises how to interpret the return value, namely

```
dumpsys window | grep 'mLandscapeRotation'
```

value 0 means: 0 and 2 are landscapes, 1 and 3 are portraits

value 1 means the opposite situation