# Android, ADB CommandLine tool get ORientation

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb

### Environment

Android SmartPhone USB connected to a Windows Desktop

### Use-case

Implement an ADB command-line tool to programatically (c++) get the current orientation

### Problem to resolve

If I would have implemented a NativeActivity I would have used "AConfiguration_fromAssetManager" followed by "AConfiguration_getOrientation".

**Given that I am implementing an ADB cmdline tool and not an activity**, how should I have this implemented?, Can I still use "AConfiguration_fromAssetManager"? Does an asset manager exist for a cmdline tool? how do I get access to it?

Any other way to get the current orientation using a C++ ADB cmdline tool ?

Answer (score 2):

Running this from the command-line worked for me:

```
adb shell "dumpsys input | grep SurfaceOrientation | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"
```

If it returns 0 or 2 the device is in portrait. If it returns 1 or 3 the device is in landscape.

**Note:** I am on a rooted device and have busybox with `grep`, `awk`, and `head` applets. You may need to parse the output of dumpsys elsewhere.

Source: [Check if device is landscape via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040624/check-if-device-is-landscape-via-adb)

Comment: Yeah, this will work though it will takes ages to execute, I need a C++ API I can directly call from my code